# Is there an easiest way to increase value in a string?

Tags: ruby

I have a string a with a lot of digits, for example `a = '4408 0412 3456 7893'`.

I want every second value (starts from `index=0`) to be multiplied by 2. And I wrote this code, but it's like a too big (and wrong) and complicated:

```
    a = '4408 0412 3456 7893'
    b = a.delete(' ')
    card = []
    c = b.split(//)

    c.each_with_index do |value, index|
      card << ((value.to_i) *2) if index % 2 == 0
    end
```

Because at the end I have an array like `[8, 0, 0, 2, 6, 10, 14, 18]` and but I should have another string like `'8408042264106148183'`.

Comment: "Increased by itself" means multiplied by 2, but then `8` becomes `16`? Or `6`? Hint: Don't split. Just edit the characters in-place. `a[2] = (a[2].to_i * 2 % 10).to_s` perhaps.

Comment: I think you are looking for the method [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-join), with no argument. Note that you can write `index % 2 == 0` as `index.even?`. There's also an `Integer` method `odd?`.

Comment: @tadman yes, I need to every second value to be multiplied by 2.

Comment: You're just looking for the output array, nothing else? This could be phrased better.

Comment: This is almost certainly about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm FYI

Comment: Try this: `i = -1; b.gsub(/./) { |s| (( i+= 1) % 3).zero? ? (2*s.to_i).to_s : '' } #=> "81628146"`, assuming it's every third, not second character you wish to double (after removing blanks).

Comment: Minimally: `a.delete(' ').chars.each_slice(2).map { |v,_| v.to_i * 2 }` To stringify that, `.join('')` on the end.

Comment: @tadman are we sure every second character starts with 0 or with 1? Obviously the change to your code is minimal e.g. `|v,_|` becomes `|_,v|` but it seems like an important detail

Comment: @engineersmnky That code produces the same array as requested.

Comment: @tadman I absolutely agree however if meager is correct then the OP code is wrong but the description in the post is still right.

Comment: @engineersmnky That's true, but that's also speculation. This may be some variant on that type of system.

Comment: You should try to improve your question even though it's been closed. (Who knows, it might be reopened) Firstly, it's irrelevant that your string represents a credit card number, and removing spaces is trivial, so you should begin with something like "Given a string of digits, such as `str = '4408041234567893'`, I wish to...". (@meagar's observation is perceptive, however.) Aside: use a variable name (e.g., `str`) that suggests its value's class. Secondly, change `% 2` in your code to `% 3` to be consistent with your verbal statement of the problem and your example...

Comment: ...Thirdly, it reads like you want to modify every third character, but your code shows you also want to remove every character whose index is not a multiple of 3. That should also be clarified.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I've edited my post before - every second value of string should be multiplied by 2!

Comment: @KevinLingard your post was closed after your last edit you will need to clarify your intention also to address what tadman and I were discussing does every second start at index 0 or index 1 and is meager correct about your reason for this post?

Comment: I hadn't noticed that. You say, "And I want every second value to be multiplied by 2." To me that suggests that if the string were "148539" you would want to change it to "2416569", but that's not what you want. You want to create a new string by extracting every other character from the first string and, treating it as an integer, doubling it. Clarify that and I'll vote to reopen. Note also that in your last line you have  '` 80026101418'`. That needs to be fixed.

Comment: @engineersmnky, yes, but I think bringing up the Luhn algorithm would unnecessarily complicate the question. It doesn't really matter why the OP wants to manipulate the string in a particular way, or that the string represents a credit card number.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it would not necessarily complicate anything and would actually lend to implementation if that were the actual reasoning if it is not then that is also acceptable; however if you were to say to me  "I want every second value to be multiplied by 2" I would assume that this would start with the second character e.g. index 1 rather than index 0 because that would be a natural counting of every second value. If it had said "every other value" then I still would ask the same but with a less assumptive position.

Comment: @engineersmnky, we'll disagree on bringing up Luhn, but I agree regarding the wording about the index. Perhaps, "I want every character having an even index into the string to be multiplied...".

Comment: @CarySwoveland Final edition of my post. Sorry for stupid clarification(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn your string into an array with integers:

```rb
array = '4408 0412 3456 7893'.delete(' ').split('').map(&:to_i)
# result: [4, 4, 0, 8, 0, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3]
```

To change the array to an array where every second (?) value is doubled:

```rb
array.each_with_index {|v,i| i.even? ? array[i] = v*2 : array[i] = v}
# result: [8, 4, 0, 8, 0, 4, 2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6, 14, 8, 18, 3]
```

To make a string of it again:

```rb
array.join('')
# result: "8408042264106148183"
```

Is this what you're looking for?